# Angular 2 OnPush Strategy doesn't see changes in Arry

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component and child.
Child have an OnPush Strategy to detect changes.
I pass throght binding () an array of objects.

But when everything is rendered and i change a field of one of objects from array the template where i list fields values doesn't update. Does anybody know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnPush` can be used only with immutability.

If you mutate your array with `push` method for example, then your component won't be updated as your array reference is still the same.

In the parent component if we take the example to add a value, you should do :

```
this.myArray = [...this.myArray, {someObjectOrWhatever: ''}] // this creates a new reference
```

If you want to remove you could use filter which returns a new array too.

But as long as you keep the same reference and have `OnPush` activated on your child component you won't see any update.